# Get All Values From Comma-Separated Eval

Tags: javascript

I understand eval can be dangerous.

`eval('exp1, exp2');` executes exp1 first, then execute exp2, the value of exp2 is the output. How do I get both values as a comma separated output?

Problem: `eval('{o1}, {o2}')` => `{o2}`.
Desired: `eval('{o1}, {o2}')` => `{o1}, {o2}`.

Comment: How about `eval('[{o1}, {o2}]');` ? Or do you want your result to be a string

Comment: With `'exp1, exp2'`, you can't. That's not how JavaScript works.